# Does CKEditor5 have an embed button like CKEditor4?

Tags: wysiwyg, 10

With CKEditor4 I was able to configure the editor to have embed buttons for entities (Webform, Taxonomy, or Node) like this using through *Configurations >> Content Authoring >> Text editor embed buttons*.

> [image: CKEditor 4 supports Entity embed]

With CKEditor5, I am lost as it has only Drupal media embed.

> [image: CKEditor 5 with no Embed option except drupal media]

*Note: Merely changing CKEditor4 to CKEditor5 is not breaking existing functionality as of now.*

How can I get Entity Embed buttons back in CKEditor5?
Is there any update regarding entity embed button that would be ported to Drupal core?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the entity embed module does not support CKEditor5 yet - mainly because the way plugins are written in CKEditor5 is different than CKEditor4.

The status looks good. I think you can get it to work with

1. The latest dev release of the 'entity_embed' module.
2. A patch for the 'embed' module from https://www.drupal.org/project/embed/issues/3309747

Comment: So, I can try working with the embed module to get it work as Drupal Media embed is already there.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu - Embed module is a dependency of the entity embed module. You will need the latest dev release of the entity embed module and use the patch for the embed module. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I will try to create another drupal instance for testing and contribute if succeed.